# How do I return struct type data in Thrift calls?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, thrift

I have the following service definition:

```
struct GAPFStatus {
    1: string faculty,
    2: bool submitted
}

service Trident {
    GAPFStatus getGAPFStatus(1: i32 faculty_id),
}
```

Inside of my server code, I'm using the following:

```
  ...

  getGAPFStatus: (facultyID, result) => {
    const status = new ttypes.GAPFStatus();
    status.faculty = facultyID;
    status.submitted = false;
    return status;
    result(null, status);
  },

  ...
```

When I use `console.log` on my status, I get `{ faculty: 10, submitted: false }`. This is correct. On the client side, I have the following code.

```
  client.getGAPFStatus(facultyID, (err, response) => {
    console.log(response);
    res.json(response);
    connection.end();
  });
```

When I used `console.log` on the response from the server, I got `undefined`. I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do in order to use my GAPFStatus structure. The Node [tutorial](https://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/nodejs) seems return the object from the server the same way that I am.

Answer (score 0):

remove return status in server side set up result(null,status) will automatically send the result back to the client.